# jQuery AJAX callback: identify if the return value from the PHP code has a given pattern

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, regex, callback

**The Objective:**
There is a login form where the user types in the username and password and clicks on a login button `(type="submit")`. I am trying to identify if the return value from the PHP code has the pattern `"FailText"` in it. If yes, display the message in div `"signinAlert"`, else (if login is successful) redirect to the user's home page.

**The Code:**

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="input_home" type="text" name="username" id="email" size="30" placeholder="E-mail Address" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="input_home" type="password" name="password" id="password" size="30" maxlength="12" placeholder="Password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;"><a href="#" title="Forgot Password">Forgot Password?</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" class="Button" value="Sign In" id="login" onclick="return DisplayLoginError()"; /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here is my JavaScript function.

```
function DisplayLoginError()
{
    var loginForm = document.loginForm;

    var dataString = $(loginForm).serialize();

    $.ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'login.php',
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data){
            var result = data;
            var patt1=new RegExp("FailText");
            if (patt1.test(result))
            {
                $('#signinAlert').html(data);
                $('#signinAlert').css('display','block');
            }
            else
            {
                window.location = "home/";
            }           
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

**The question:**
I strongly believe that the above JavaScript code is very sloppy (because of the RegExp evaluation when the login attempt is a success). Is there any other way to achieve the objective? By the way, the above method works on ALL major browsers.

Comment: what is the value returned by the server in case of a failed login

Comment: Don't abuse `placeholder` like that, it isn't a `<label>`.

Comment: @ArunPJohny After verifying that the user's credentials were correct, I was setting a few session variables and redirecting to the user's home page -- header( 'Location: home/' );  In other words, if I didn't have the RegExp check, the user's home page was loading in the div "signinAlert" and not redirecting.

Comment: @Quentin Will keep it in mind. Thanks.

Comment: I normally just echo out a `json_encode()`'ed array, in your case from login.php. Something like `echo json_encode("message"=>"There was a problem logging you in", "type"=>"error");` - Then in your javascript: `var result = $.parseJSON(data);  $('#signinAlert').html(result.message);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my preferred option. Not saying it's perfect but it's what I've been using for a while. Just means that all your error messages are stored in PHP rather than in your JS files (which I prefer). Also note, the below code is untested.

**Edit**: *Just a note as to why I prefer the errors in PHP instead of JS. I normally have a table with my errors in, meaning I can output the error code and message just by saying `oh this is ERR-002, output the message associated with it`. When somebody phones up with ERR-002, I only need to check the DB (and not trawl through code).*

On your login.php page, you can return a json encoded array that javascript can decode. So in your php:

```
<?php 

    $arrResult = array("message" => "Could not log you in", "type" => "error");
    // Or the success one:
    // $arrResult = array("message" => "You're logged in", "type" => "success"); 
    echo json_encode($arrResult);

?>
```

Then you can decode this message and use it as an object in javascript, like so:

```
function DisplayLoginError()
{
    var loginForm = document.loginForm;

    var dataString = $(loginForm).serialize();

    $.ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'login.php',
        data: dataString,
        success: function(strResponse){
            var $objResponse = $.parseJSON(strResponse);

            if ($objResponse.type == "success")
            {
                 window.location = "home/";
            }
            else
            {
                 $('#signinAlert').html($objResponse.message).css('display','block');
            }           
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Was trying to absorb your earlier answer by googling "JSON tutorial". LOL. This helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It works great but sometimes if the data have leading or trailing spaces it will not match the pattern so its good practice to use `data=$.trim(data);`before matching pattern

Comment: You're right. However in this case, I would know if login failed "FailText" would be there as is (it's a css class I am using). However to make things leaner, I have added the trim function.